# WPF Grid set background color and png image

Tags: wpf

I have `Grid` (3x3) in my main window and want to have a background color (which changes when I press button in other window) and background image (which also changes on click of same button) in the first `Grid` cell (`Row="0"`, `Column="0"`).

**MainWindow XAML** (code just for first `Grid` (0,0)):

```
<Grid x:Name="Q1Grid"
        Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0">
        
    <Border x:Name="Q1Border" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            >
        <TextBlock x:Name="Q1TB"
            Style="{StaticResource CategoryTextBlock}"
            Text="Category 1" 
            MouseLeftButtonUp="Q1_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush  x:Name="Q1P"
                ImageSource="{DynamicResource Transparent}"
                         Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

In another window (`Q1`) I have this code:

```
private void Q1C_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Q1TB.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Q1Grid.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
    var correct = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pictures/Joc pravilen - transparent.png"));
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Q1P.ImageSource = correct;

    this.Close();
}
```

I can only get background color and not image or vice-versa, but I can not get both. I tried many options:

- Set background color to `Grid` (0,0), but then due to round corners, background color is out ob those corners
- Set color and image to `Border` and/or `TextBlock` and none)

None gave me the wanted result. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `Background` of an element twice, but you can add a second border `Q1BackgroundBorder` that displays the background color and is behind the `Q1Border`.

```
<Grid x:Name="Q1Grid"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="0">
   <Border x:Name="Q1BackgroundBorder"/>
   <Border x:Name="Q1Border" 
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0">
      <!-- ...other XAML code. -->
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

Set the background of the `Q1BackgroundBorder` in your `Q1C_Click` click handler.

```
((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).Q1BackgroundBorder.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. It is really easy solution that just works.